# How to add a parameter to login page and access in loadUserByUsername method spring security 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

While user tries to login I want to pass an extra parameter userAccountID,
and access in loadUserByUsername for querying db user with name and userAccountID.

```
userDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException;
```

How can I achieve this above user case?

Thanks in advance.

Below is my login Java configuration but it not working empty login page in coming

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl getAuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl() throws Exception
{
    return new AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl();
}


@Bean
public TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception{
    TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter authFilter = new TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter();
    authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler( authenticationSuccessHandler );
    authFilter.setPostOnly( true );
    return authFilter;
}


@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception
{
    return super.authenticationManager();
}

@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{

    http    .addFilterBefore( new TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class )
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage( "/403" )
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/login**" ).permitAll()
            /*.antMatchers( "/admin*//**" ).hasRole( "ADMIN" )*/
            .antMatchers( "/adminPage" ).access( "hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" )
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().loginPage( "/login" ).failureUrl( "/login?error" )
            .usernameParameter( "username" ).passwordParameter( "password" )
            //.successHandler( authenticationSuccessHandler )
            .and()
            .logout().invalidateHttpSession( true ).deleteCookies( "JSESSIONID" ).logoutUrl( "/logout" ).logoutSuccessUrl( "/logout-success" )
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .invalidSessionUrl( "/login" )
            .maximumSessions( 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend your UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. Under the obtainUsername method, you can take the another parameter.

```
public class TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
{   
    @Override
    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String username = request.getParameter(getUsernameParameter());
        String extraInput = request.getParameter("userAccountID");
        String combinedUsername = username + ":" + extraInput;
        return combinedUsername;
    }
}
```

Now you can modify your loadUserByUsername method as:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String input) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException
{
    String[] split = input.split(":");
    String username = split[0];
    String extraInput = split[1];

    // and your queries etc
```

This is an easy way. For full tutorial you can visit here:
http://blog.awnry.com/post/16183749439/two-factor-authentication-and-spring-security-3